# Getting 403 error when using CSRF filter with tomcat 6.0.32

Tags: security, tomcat, csrf

This is my filer config in web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
        <param-value>/login<param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
```

Am I missing something? Are any code-changes necessary to enable csrf protection in tomcat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that a **403** is the [CSRFPreventionFilter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_0/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/CsrfPreventionFilter.java) response if a nonce is not provided and the filter expects one.

I don't know the current state of **CSRFPreventionFilter**, but according to [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg88601.html) you need to specify each **entryPoint** resource individually (no wildcards) - or have the filter apply to a path that does not include **/login**

So:

```xml
<filter>
<filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
    <param-value>/login/login.html,/login/image.png,/login/style.css</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
```

Or:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/csrf/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Update Dec 2012:**

Tomcat [7.0.32](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-7.html#Fixed_in_Apache_Tomcat_7.0.32) fixes a security vulnerability in **CSRFPreventionFilter**

Comment: Thanks for the explantion. So my question now is do I need to change anything in my jsps to send the nonce, or will tomcat take care of that. Because as I understand, the getRedirectUrl method is over-written by this filer, so any links in my code will get handled automatically. But what about the forms in my pages?

Comment: I haven't actually tried it - but I would expect the form action would need encodeUrl().

Comment: Thanks.. I guess I will have to also send hidden parameter in case of form posts

Comment: Has there been any updates to this filter?  I am currently running into the same issue but have over 300 jsp's, each with multiple links.  I would love it if someone has come up with something to avoid having to wrap each link with 'urlEncode'

Comment: @james Donnelly, param-value only for skipping resource for entry point I'm facing also same issue. Do you have any solution for that I tried in same way but always getting access denied 403 page. Ref: https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/e5be9994bb571014b575a785961062db.html