# Setting up CsrfPreventionFilter in Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, csrf-protection

I am attempting to set up the inbuilt CsrfPreventionFilter in Tomcat 8.

I think I have read all the questions and answers in StackOverflow on this subject, but I can still not solve my problem.

I have `home.jsp` and `reports.jsp`

The URL of `home.jsp` (once it has been subjected to `response.encodeUrl()`) is
`www.example.com/home.jsp?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=5E4BD8FEE1B4CC1DA79D874905015911`

This is rendered correctly, not because the nonce is working, but because I set `home.jsp` to be an EntryPoint. However it does seem to prove that the CSRFPreventionFilter is up and running and generating nonces successfully.

If I press CTRL+N and then type in `www.example.com/reports.jsp` and then I add the same nonce, i.e. `www.example.com/reports.jsp?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=5E4BD8FEE1B4CC1DA79D874905015911` then I get page 403. `reports.jsp` is not set up as an EntryPoint, but I would expect it to render successfully, as it has been supplied with a nonce.

What am I doing wrong?

(My question is somewhat similar to [Getting 403 error when using CSRF filter with tomcat 6.0.32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151768/getting-403-error-when-using-csrf-filter-with-tomcat-6-0-32); but I feel that the answer is probably not in the way the CSRFPrevention Filter is set up, but perhaps some issue in the way I am dealing with the response/request internally, akin to @Pankaj Kumar's answer in  [Not able to authenticate post request for CSRF token with tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530341/not-able-to-authenticate-post-request-for-csrf-token-with-tomcat))

**UPDATE**

Here is the web.xml configuration

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
            <param-value>/images/404.JPG,/login.jsp,/home.jsp,/images/im_login.gif,/js/events.js,/js/menu.js,/js/amount_validation.js,/js/calendar.js,/js/toolbar.js,/js/tablesort.js,/js/scripts.js,/css/style.css</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: what is `filter-mapping` for  `CsrfPreventionFilter`?

Comment: I updated my question with the web.xml configuration

Comment: how many links - more specifically calls to `response.encodeUrl()` are on home.jsp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove js, css and image paths from `entryPoints` and setup filter mapping for `CsrfPreventionFilter` in such a way that it does not include them.

The reason is that in tomcat the nonceCache has a size of 5 by default. In your case when js, css are requested, tomcat generates a new nonce (since they are in entryPoints) and adds it to cache, after 5 such requests your initial nonce (generated for home.jsp) is flushed out of nonceCache and is no longer valid. So you get a `403` when you send a legit request with that nonce.